# In Flash Builder 4.5 (flex mobile app)

Tags: flash, builder

I'm trying to bind to multiple tables, but for some reason, it keeps referring to the first binding I made to the first table. I binded through ArrayCollection. Is there anyway to bind to multiple tables?

Comment: So you have multiple collections or arrays (which you refer to as tables) and you want them to be presented as a single collection?

Comment: I have multiple ArrayCollections, but I want to be able to add multiple tables either within the same ArrayCollection or different one/

Comment: There's no such thing as a table on the Flex side. The Flex side sends a request to the PHP and the PHP returns a result - in your case the result is apparently a XML. What's the structure of this XML?

Comment: Well, actually i was asking the wrong question. The question is how do you get flash to read multiple tables based on relationship (primary/foreign keys)

Comment: There are plenty of ways - the most widely adopted way is to use an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) which translates the Relational database model into an object oriented model. In PHP for example you can use Doctrine. Once converted into an object model you can transfer collections of typed objects over the wire, not tables. The protocol used for such transfer is most likely to be HTTP where the payload of the HTTP response is most likely to be serialized with AMF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection(tableData1.concat(tableData2,..., tableDataN))}"
```

Comment: So would it work in this case where buildingListData is a ArrayCollection                                                    `code` <s:List id = "userList" width="100%" height="100%" 
   labelField="buildingName"  
   dataProvider="{buildingListData}" 
   change="showStatus(event)" />

Comment: What's inside this `buildingListData`?

Comment: It has the data from mySQL/PHP in xml format where I can access the data easier